# Rutherford gold experiment

Tags: electrostatics, experimental-physics, atomic-physics, atoms

When an alpha particle is nearing the gold atoms nucleus, it is slowing down due  to electrostatic repulsion, right? 
But then why is the acceleration or velocity not a minimum at that point (the point where the alpha particle reverses its direction)and why is the speed a minimum? 
Like isn't the resultant force on the alpha particle reducing which should cause its acceleration to be minimum?

Answer (score 2):

The electrostatic repulsion force becomes larger as the particles are brought closer together. Since force is proportional to acceleration, this must mean that the acceleration is at a maximum when the particles are at their closest distance.

When something changes direction, the velocity vector changes direction. Therefore, at the point of changing directions the velocity is $0$.

Comment: i know its kind of stupid, but wont resultant force be reduced as it nears the nucleus?

Comment: @Meganmars The electrostatic force between two charges grows as they get closer. Can you explain your reasoning more? Maybe I am missing something.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't that because the electrostatic force invert the sense of the acceleration vector, reducing particle's speed to a minimum at that point? So the speed will be minimum, and acceleration maximum, but oriented in the opposite direction, which makes the alpha particle to reflect.